# Unfinished code (Simple payroll) - javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me solve what is the formula in "othrs" (overtime hours)

```
    var name, hrs, rate = 120, otrate = 150, othrs, bpay, otpay, gpay, ded, npay
    name = prompt("Enter your name")
    hrs = prompt("Enter hours worked")

    othrs = 
    bpay = hrs * rate
    otpay = othrs * otrate
    gpay = bpay + otpay
    ded = bpay * .10
    npay = gpay - ded

    if (hrs < 40) {
    hrs = 40
    }

    alert("Name: " + name + "\nNo. of hours worked: " + hrs + "\nNo. of overtime hours: " + othrs + "\nBasic pay: " + bpay + "\nOvertime pay: " + otpay + "\nGross pay: " + gpay + "\nDeduction: " + ded + "\nNet pay: " + npay)
```

Comment: That is partly what this assignment is tasking **you** to figure out. What formula have you come up with so far to make that calculation?

Comment: Our professor gave that. The problem is I don't recall what to put in the 'othrs' (overtime hours) formula. The regular hours is 40 so it should be that the excess of 40 is the othrs.

Comment: presumably it's `hrs - whateverfulltimeisconsidered`. Or you could ask your professor.

Comment: Question:  "Can you please help me solve what is the formula in "othrs" (overtime hours)"   Answer:  "No"

Comment: @HowardRenollet I'd upvote that.

Comment: If you can't remember, then simply figure it out again. Trying to operate purely by memorization is a very bad habit for a programmer. Matt Burland has given you a **huge** hint; see if you can figure it out from there.

Comment: I have a different answer that is fine and working but my prof said that it is not structured.

Comment: @batman Post your solution to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask how it could be refactored so that it is "more structured" in that case.

Comment: Yep Mr. Burland answer is also my answer on my other code but take note that if statement the one that our prof used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this question isn't getting closed, I may as well answer it.  See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jaozc7zd/

Now, this isn't the most efficient way to do this and I'm not going to refactor your code for you, but here's your answer:

```
var name, hrs, rate = 120, otrate = 150, othrs, bpay, otpay, gpay, ded, npay
name = prompt("Enter your name")
hrs = prompt("Enter hours worked")

othrs = hrs > 40 ? hrs - 40 : 0;
bpay = (hrs >= 40 ? 40 : hrs) * rate
otpay = othrs * otrate
gpay = bpay + otpay
ded = bpay * .10
npay = gpay - ded

alert("Name: " + name + "\nNo. of hours worked: " + hrs + "\nNo. of overtime hours: " + othrs + "\nBasic pay: " + bpay + "\nOvertime pay: " + otpay + "\nGross pay: " + gpay + "\nDeduction: " + ded + "\nNet pay: " + npay)
```